# C-listing the biggest vicinity of same numbers in a matrix

Tags: c, matrix, iteration

I am new to programming. I know that my question might not be very smart, but please bear with me. I mention that this is not a homework.

I would like to find the number of vicinities, how many 1's each consists of and the coordinates of the most up-left cell in each vicinity.

For example, for the following matrix:

```
{1, 1, 1, 0, 1}
{0, 0, 1, 0, 1}
{0, 1, 1, 0, 0}
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

In this example there are two groups of 1's. The first one has six 1's and the second one has two 1's.

Below I post my source code so far. It prints the right answer only for some matrices, because my code checks for 1's only one field up, one field down, one field right and one field left. I would like to know how to get rid of this problem, without using a recursive approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define m 4
#define n 5

int Check(int A[][100],int i,int j,int Checked[][100])
{
    if(A[i][j]==1 && Checked[i][j]==0)
    {
        Checked[i][j]=1;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int A[100][100],i,j,Checked[100][100],begin=0;
    int counter=0;
    int base[100];
    int k=0,x=0;
    int lines[100],cols[100];

srand(time(NULL));

for(i=0;i<m;i++)//generating random matrix
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        A[i][j]=rand()%2;
        printf("%d ",A[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

for(i=0;i<m;i++)//initialising with 0 the Checked matrix
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        Checked[i][j]=0;
    }
}

for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(Checked[i][j]==0)
        {
            Checked[i][j]=1;

            if(A[i][j]==1 && begin==0)
            {
                lines[x]=i;
                cols[x]=j;
                begin=1;
                x++;
                counter++;
            }
            if(A[i][j]==1)
            {
                if(Check(A,i-1,j,Checked)==1)
                    counter++;
                if(Check(A,i,j+1,Checked)==1)
                    counter++;
                if(Check(A,i+1,j,Checked)==1)
                    counter++;
                if(Check(A,i,j-1,Checked)==1)
                    counter++;
                if(Check(A,i-1,j,Checked)==0 && Check(A,i,j+1,Checked)==0 && Check(A,i+1,j,Checked)==0 && Check(A,i,j-1,Checked)==0)
                {
                    base[k]=counter;
                    counter=0;
                    k++;
                    begin=0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

for(i=0;i<k;i++)
{
    printf("\nNumber of bases: %d\n",base[i]);
    printf("Most up-left base coords: <%d, %d> \n",lines[i],cols[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Thanks, Polb

Comment: Use stack for DFS or use queue for BFS.

Comment: How do you define "a recursive approach" that should be avoided here?

Comment: By "recursive approach" I mean defining a function that would call itself to check whether the next element on the line or on the column is equal to 1 or not. This would check all the next elements on the current row and column, but for bigger matrices I guess that the program would crash (because of the stack limit).

Comment: Could you explain me in short about DFS or give me a link to a tutorial, please?

Comment: @Polb Depth-first search and breadth-first search. The one I showed below is depth-first using a stack (similar to the vanilla recursive solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, goofy pseudocode:

```
int count_connected(set* traversed, element starting_element):
{
    int count = 0
    if set_insert(traversed, starting_element):
    {
        stack* to_process = stack_create()
        stack_push(to_process, starting_element)

        while not stack_empty(to_process):
        {
            element current_element = to_process.pop()
            for each adj_element to current_element:
            {
                if set_insert(traversed, adj_element):
                {
                    ++count
                    stack_push(to_process, adj_element)
                }
            }
        }
        stack_destroy(to_process)
    }
    return count
}
```

`set_insert` would return false when trying to insert a duplicate.

Some modifications to this basic pseudocode for your case: `element` would be a position into the matrix (a point/position kind of `struct` or two separate integers).

`for each adj_element` would traverse neighboring positions that have a value of `1` (like your current code now checking entries to the left, above, below, and to the right with bounds-checking). To avoid a boatload of code, you can construct an array of 4 positions on the stack consisting of neighboring positions, loop through them, check if they are in bounds, and if they are not already in the `traversed` set.

Your `traversed` set can be a matrix of the same size, treated as a matrix of booleans initialized to 0 (false) for constant-time set insertion. Or you could also make your ordinary matrix into a matrix of `structs` which store a `traversed` flag. That kind of interleaved rep would tend to be more efficient if you ever use a really large matrix and this flag is accessed very often (hot). Separating it could be useful if it's not always needed to reduce the memory requirements and possible alignment overhead. You could also jam it all together using bitwise logic where a matrix entry is storing both a `1/0` value and whether it has been traversed all in one integral type.

With the above function implemented, you can call it over a loop iterating through the matrix from top-left to bottom-right for the `1` entries. Since we keep this `traversed` set across calls, it'll return 0 for matrix entries which have already been traversed. The ones that return non-zero would only do so for the top-left vicinity since we're iterating through the matrix from top-left to bottom-right calling this `count_connected` function.

When we call the function for position 0,0 as the `starting_element`, for example, we end up traversing this region in a depth-first fashion using the stack and set:

```
{*, *, *, 0, 1}
{0, 0, *, 0, 1}
{0, *, *, 0, 0}
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

And the function returns `6` which you can print out along with the top-left coordinate, `0,0`. When you next call it for `1,0`, it'll return `0` and you can skip that.

If you want to allow the function to be called in an arbitrary order and still return the top-left element, you can keep track of the element positions in the function and return the one the top-left one that way (minimum `y` and `x`). Note that `top-left` gets ambiguous a bit if you have, say:

```
{0, 0, 1, 0, 1}
{0, 0, 1, 0, 1}
{1, 1, 1, 0, 0}
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

I'm assuming you want `2,0` in that case along with the count, which you'll get with the above methods. If you want an upper-left corner (like a bounding box corner), the second method will work if you output `min(x)` and `min(y)` among the element positions you traverse, in which case you'll get `0,0`.

I'll leave the rest to you.